# HTML5 Video not displaying video from axios react data fetch

Tags: axios, sequelize.js, html5-video, http-status-code-404

I am having issue with my video player page, not being able to find the data associated with the video file. I keep getting a 404 not found or a "undefined error coming from the axios code snippet of my code as that is where the console log for it is located. However, the object of data also appears in the console but the url remains undefined and so does the video player.

Here is the code for the backend, this is through the routing:
upload.js:

```
const { sequelize, video } = require('../models');

    router.post("/getVideo", async (req, res) => {
        
            try {
                const getvideo = await video.findOne({
                    "_id" : req.body.videoId
                })
        
                return res.json(getvideo)
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
                return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Something went wrong' });
            }
        })
```

The sequeilize console appears to be functional

Here is the code for the frontend:
Detailvideopage.js

```
const DetailVideoPage = (props) => {
        let { videoId } = useParams();
        const [video, setVideo] = useState([]);
    
        const videoVariable = {
            videoId: videoId
        }
    
        useEffect(() => {
            axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/upload/getVideo', videoVariable, {
                headers: {
                    'accept': 'application/json',
                },
            })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.data.success) {
                    console.log(response.data.video)
                    setVideo(response.data.video)
                    console.log(response.data.success);
                } else {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    alert('Failed to get video Info')
                }
        }).catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
    
    }, []);
    
        return (
            <div className="postPage" style={{ width: '100%', padding: '3rem 4em' }} >
            <video style={{ width: '100%' }} src={`http://localhost:5000/${video.filePath}`} controls></video>
    
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Here is an image of the error I receive from my localhost page: [localhost console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/of1E8.png)

Here is the routes for the frontend:
import DetailVideoPage from `'./components/views/DetailVideoPage/DetailVideoPage';`

```
<Router>
      <Routes>
      <Route exact path='/video/:videoId' element={<DetailVideoPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
```

UPDATE: I have renamed the question to more accurately display the nature of the issue. The main issue is that even though the data is fetched, the video is not being displayed.

Comment: I am certain none of the errors in the image are from the code you've shared above. There is a GET request error for `"http://localhost:5000/undefined"`. Search your code for where you are rendering something forming a request URL with `":videoId"` around line 44. The error on the screen seems to be something else entirely, looks like a React version mismatch maybe, between some packages in your `package.json` file.

Comment: I do get the alert of "failed to get video info" even though the object is loaded, would this mean I'd probably have to use different dependecies and/or add packages to get my current line of code to work?

Comment: It seems like you are making several video requests simultaneously, some succeed and at least one is failing. Can you provide a more [complete and comprehensive code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I have provided more information about my code example while providing the exact code that deals with my issue. I hope this makes things much more clear.

Comment: Basically you need to get an MP4 file path. Does this line `console.log(response.data.video)` actually show you any file paths? **What happens** if you put the path String into a variable like example `var let myPath = XXXX;` then use that same _"myPath"_ in your video `.src` setting??? Try `console.log( "JSON keys : " + Object.keys(response.data.video) );` to see if you got the expected entries for getting video path.

Comment: With my original `console.log(response.data.video)` it does show the entirity of the schema with the associated `Id` including the direct fliepath of where the video is located.  When I tried `console.log( "JSON keys : " + Object.keys(response.data.video) );` it gave me an error stating `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)** however when I removed the .video, it returned **JSON keys : id,title,filePath,description,thumbnail,duration,createdAt,updatedAt`

For the *mypath* string is there any documentation that you can reference?

Comment: @Donnyb **(1)** For testing... After `console.log(response.data.video);` add the line `let myPath = response.data.filePath; alert( "MP4 path is : " + myPath);` Now does it show a correct MP4 path. **(2)** Your `return` of HTML code is a bit dodgy (where does it return it to? and how is it added to the page?). Why not just create actual DIV and Video elements by JS code then append those elements to page? ... Anyways your first priority is to get a video file path then worry how to display afterwards.

Comment: I have added the let mypath and alert and it does return with the correct filepath for the object associated with the correct id. As for the return, I have seen examples either using the inital usestate with `video` in the `src` of the video tag, or an associalted url. I should probably rename this question as "Video not loading from response" as that is the crux of the problem. It's the display of the videofile, not the fetching of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION:
I have found the solution with the advice of VC.One and a bit of research, much thanks to him!

I have refactored some of my code for my DetailVideoPage.JS:

```
function DetailVideoPage() {
  const [Video, setVideo] = useState([]);

  const videoId = useParams();

  const videoVariable = {
    videoId: videoId
  }

  useEffect(() => {

    const getSingleVideoData = async () => {
      axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/upload/getVideo', videoVariable)
      .then(response => {
              console.log(response);
              setVideo(response.data.filePath);
            //   let myPath = response.data.filePath; 
            //   alert( "MP4 path is : " + myPath);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
      });

    }
    getSingleVideoData();

  }, []);


  return (

    <>
      <Row>
          <Col lg={18} xs={24}>
          <div className="postPage" style={{ width: '100%', padding: '3rem 4em' }}>
          <video style={{ width: '100%' }} src={`http://localhost:5000/${Video}`} type='video/mp4' controls autoPlay muted />
          </div>
          </Col>
      </Row>

      </>
  )
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For testing... See if this shows a video on the page:

```
const DetailVideoPage = (props) => {
        let { videoId } = useParams();
        const [video, setVideo] = useState([]);
    
        const videoVariable = { videoId: videoId }
        
        var myDiv; var myVid;
    
        useEffect(() => {
            axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/upload/getVideo', videoVariable, {
                headers: {
                    'accept': 'application/json',
                },
            })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.data.success) 
                {
                    console.log(response.data.video)
                    setVideo(response.data.video)
                    console.log(response.data.success);
                    
                    ///////////////////////////////////
                    //# test adding of Video
                    
                    //# create the Div
                    myDiv = document.createElement('div');
                    myDiv.setAttribute("id", "myDiv");

                    //# create the Video object
                    myVid = document.createElement( "video");
                    myVid.setAttribute("id", "myVid");
                    myVid.setAttribute("controls", "true" );
                    myVid.setAttribute("height", "500");
                    myVid.setAttribute("src", path);
                    myVid.load();

                    //# add Video into Div, then finally add Div to page
                    myDiv.appendChild( myVid );
                    document.body.appendChild( myDiv );
                    
                    ///////////////////////////////////
                } 
                else 
                {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    alert('Failed to get video Info')
                }
        }).catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
    
    }, []);
        
        //# If needed... see if returning the Div works...
        //return ( myDiv );
        
        /*
        return (
            <div className="postPage" style={{ width: '100%', padding: '3rem 4em' }} >
            <video style={{ width: '100%' }} src={`http://localhost:5000/${video.filePath}`} controls></video>
    
            </div>
        );
        */
}
```

Comment: I have actually gotten the video to show with your advice from your previous comment and abit of research to display the video. :) I will be posting the solution. I will be trying to figure out why my url is undefined but that's a seperate issue I will be focusing on for another day lol